# How to truncate decimal space in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to get the size of database and wanna display it to the GUI. Thats what i am using

```
select 
sum(((((CAST(saf.[size] as DECIMAL(18,4)) * 8192) /1024) /1024) /1024)) as 'Size'
from sys.sysdatabases sdb
inner join sys.sysaltfiles saf
on sdb.dbid = saf.dbid
where sdb.name = 'testDB'
```

Result is :-

```
3.8329467773437500000
```

But i want it to be trimmed or round up like this :-

```
3.84
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rounding instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

I didn't see your unique rounding issue. This looks interesting:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196652

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(
    CEILING (
        sum(((((CAST(saf.[size] as DECIMAL(18,4)) * 8192) /1024) /1024) /1024))
    * 100)
AS decimal(18,2)
) / 100
```

- 3.8329467773437500000
- -> 383.29467773437500000 (* 100)
- -> 384.00000000... (CEILING)
- -> 384.00  (to decimal 18, 2)
- -> 3.84  (/ 100)